# linking a php switch to html php pages

Tags: php, html, switch-statement, href

Hello I am trying to link a PHP switch statement with some PHP files that are within html links. Basically I have one file that has a switch statement and I'm trying to link that with html some html href and html dropdown list so that they can redirect to another PHP page. I apologize if this has already been posted I couldn't find anything that could help.
Here's the file with html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="NavMenu">
<a href="index.php?page=Home"> HOME </a>
<a href="index.php?page=Gallery"> GALLERY </a>

<select name='page' id='page'>
  <option value="DieRoller">DieRoller</option>
  <option value="Converter">Converter</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the file that's handling the switch statement:

```
<?php
    
    require_once('includes/NavMenu.php');
    

     
?>
<HTML>
<div id= "DynamicContent">
<?php
    $page = $_REQUEST['page'] ?? "null";
    if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    
    echo $page = $_GET['page'];   
 
     switch($page){
    case 'Home':
        echo 'HOME';
        break;
     case 'Gallery':
         require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\Gallery.php';
         break;
    case 'DieRoller':
        require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\DieRoller.php';
        break;
    case 'Converter':
        require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\converter.php';
        break;
      default:
         echo 'not';
         break;
    }
 }
 ?>
</div>
</HTML>
```

Comment: why do you have <html> tag inside the file with switch statement?

Comment: For the <div id= "DynamicContent"> so I can go back with some css and make it look nice

Comment: you only have one html tag like in NavMenu.php file and all elements have to be inside body tag. since you already close html tag in NavMenu.php you cannot open a new html tag afterwards.

Comment: I'm not opening a new html tag. I only have 1 open and 1 close on each file.

Comment: those files are combined into one page and you are supposed to have one tag for each page.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue